# Surpress double photos in Google Glass timeline?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Currently when you share a photo from Glass, that action leaves a card in your timeline. (For example, sharing a pic to G+ results in a second timeline card of that picture with a little G+ icon in the lower-right corner)

If you share immediately after taking a picture, you end up with two copies of that picture next to each other, which quickly becomes cumbersome.

Ideally, a SHARE action (or a contact registered to receive those actions) would include a flag such as "persist card" or "don't show SHARE card".

Other than immediately deleting the timeline id responsible for the share (which isn't very synchronous), does anyone have any idea how to share many photos without cluttering up the timeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new timeline card is created whenever a user shares or replies. This card is intended to be used as a place where your Glassware provides functionality to the user. For example, as a photo receives comments, you could add them as items to a bundle with this card. Or, you could allow the user to delete the photo they shared by adding a delete menu item to that card. In other words, we strongly recommend against deleting it.

That being said, if you'd really like to delete it, it sounds like you've found the best technique: to delete the card using [timeline delete](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/delete) method.